# Android DatePicker layout customisation

Tags: android, android-datepicker

When DatePicker is displayed with calendar view, is it possible to have additional label with some text at the bottom of this calendar view (as shown on the picture)? I've tried looking if there is a possibility to customise original Android DatePicker, can't see any suitable way of doing it.

[image: datepicker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the source code from [here](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

In order to customize layout as you want, you should modify `layout-land/mdtp_date_picker_dialog.xml` and `layout-sw600dp-land/mdtp_date_picker_dialog.xml` fiels. Here I have added two `TextViews` as your screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mdtp_background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/mdtp_date_picker_header_view" />

            <include layout="@layout/mdtp_date_picker_selected_date" />

            <include layout="@layout/mdtp_date_picker_footer_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/added_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Some Text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/mdtp_date_picker_view_animator" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/added_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/mdtp_done_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Change related `dimens` to locate the `TextViews` as you want.

Comment: Still working on it, but looks like it is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Is this guaranteed not to break in future versions of android ?  I did not see an official API from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue a while back. I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) library.

You can customise this library in any way you want. Just edit its layout file and expand the particular layout you want to. You can also add labels easily in the layout files.

Hope it helps.